# Testing after_commit with RSpec and mocking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

I have a model Lead and a callback: `after_commit :create, :send_to_SPL`

I am using Rails-4.1.0, ruby-2.1.1, RSpec.

1) This spec is not passing:

```
context 'callbacks' do
  it 'shall call \'send_to_SPL\' after create' do
    expect(lead).to receive(:send_to_SPL)
    lead = Lead.create(init_hash)
    p lead.new_record? # => false
  end
end
```

2) This spec is not passing too:

```
context 'callbacks' do
  it 'shall call \'send_to_SPL\' after create' do
    expect(ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback).to receive(:build)
    lead = Lead.create(init_hash)
  end
end
```

3) This one is passing, but I think it is not testing after_commit callback:

```
context 'callbacks' do
  it 'shall call \'send_to_SPL\' after create' do
    expect(lead).to receive(:send_to_SPL)
    lead.send(:send_to_SPL)
  end
end
```

What is the best way to test after_commit callbacks in Rails?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try to use [test_after_commit](https://github.com/grosser/test_after_commit) gem

or add following code in spec/support/helpers/test_after_commit.rb - [Gist](https://gist.github.com/cmaitchison/5168104)

Comment: You also can use `subject.run_callbacks(:commit)` in the end of the body of the block `it`

Comment: This gem works fantastic for Rails 3 and Rails 4. In Rails 5, it's no longer necessary because it's been added to the core: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18458/commits/eb72e349b205c47a64faa5d6fe9f831aa7fdddf3

Answer (score 60):

I thought [Mihail Davydenkov's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988968/testing-after-commit-with-rspec-and-mocking/30901628#comment43748375_22989816) deserved to be an answer:

> You can also use `subject.run_callbacks(:commit)`.

Also note that this issue (commit callbacks not getting called in transactional tests) should be fixed in rails 5.0+ so you may wish to make a note to remove any workarounds you may use in the meantime when you upgrade.  See: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18458

Comment: I doesn't work on `4.2.7` if callback defined with `on: :update`. I had to also do `subject.instance_variable_get(:@_start_transaction_state)[:new_record]=false` before running callbacks to make it work

Comment: Though it executes the callback but self.previous_changes are { } which is not true. How to get that?

Answer (score 12):

I'm using [DatabaseCleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner), with a configuration where I can easily switch between transaction and truncation, where the former is preferred, because of speed, but where the latter can be used for testing callbacks.

RSpec `before` and `after` handlers work with scopes, so if you want to make truncation a scope, define a `before` handler;

```
config.before(:each, truncate: true) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end
```

And now to use this configuration for a `describe`, `context` or `it` block, you should declare it like:

```
describe "callbacks", truncate: true do
   # all specs within this block will be using the truncation strategy
  describe "#save" do
    it "should trigger my callback" do
      expect(lead).to receive(:send_to_SPL)
      lead = Lead.create(init_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

Complete hook configuration: (store in `spec/support/database_cleaner.rb`)

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, truncate: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.append_after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Update for **Rails5**.

Callback handling has indeed been fixed, but you may still need to use `#reload` liberally.

An example:
Given a model that defines an after-create callback like so:

```
after_create_commit { assign_some_association }
```

You can spec this behavior with:

```
describe "callbacks" do
  describe "assigning_some_association" do
    subject(:saving) { record.save!; record.reload } # reload here is important

    let(:record) { build(:record) }

    it "assigns some association after commit" do        
      expect{ saving }.to(
        change{ record.some_association_id }.from(nil).to(anything)
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this

```
describe 'some method on record' do
  let(:record) { create(:some_record) }
  let(:update_block) { ->(record) { record.save! } } # define an labmda that will be called in a transaction block
  let(:result_method) { :some_method } # define a method to be called
  let(:result) do
    record.class_eval <<~EVAL, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
      after_commit :_record_result
       def _record_result
        @_result = public_send(:#{result_method})
      end
    EVAL

    record.transaction do
      update_block.call(record)
    end

    record.instance_variable_get(:'@_result')
  end

  before do
    # apply changes to record
  end

  it 'returns the correct result' do
    expect(result).to eq(some_value)
  end
end
```